# How to enter a large string in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm working in a program that needs to compare strings that have about 900 digits.
But whenever I enter them as

```
a = '01111111111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111010101000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111100001010101000010100'
```

Python only takes the first line as the string, and it says error.
In which way can I enter it so that Python takes the complete string?
Thanks

Comment: You have shown only one line. What is the `first line` here?

Answer (score 6):

You mean you need to enter a multi-line string with newlines?

Use triple quoting:

```
a = '''This is the first line
and a second one too
hello world!
'''
```

Newlines are preserved, as is all whitespace.

If you *didn't* want to include newlines, use parenthesis around multiple strings:

```
a = (
    'This is one string, '
    'entirely without newlines, but it is one long '
    'string nonetheless')
```

The Python compiler makes such consecutive strings (without anything but whitespace in between) into one long string object.

However, a 900 digit string is perhaps best stored in a separate file, not in your source code:

```
with open('digitsfile.txt', 'r') as infh:
    a = infh.read().strip()  # read all data, remove newline at the end
```

Comment: How can I store it in a separate file?

Comment: @user3103718: you could use a text editor to write that string into a separate file, perhaps? I've given you the two lines to read such a file, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The Python compiler concatenates adjacent string literals. You just need to tell the compiler that the literals are adjacent.

```
a = (
  '123'
  '456'
  '789'
)

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can skip new line by `\`:

```
>>> num = '12345' \
...       '67890'
>>> num
'1234567890'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no carriage return in the string somewhere, that would cause an error.

Try enclosing the string in triple quotes

```
s = """really long strrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrring"""
```

and then echo it back

```
print s
```